# filling a text view from a json file not working

Tags: java, android, json, android-edittext

hi I'm fairly new to android studio

i have this JSON tree

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "jhon",
    "salary": 1500
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "sal",
    "salary": 1700
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "bob",
    "salary": 2500
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "ned",
    "salary": 1800
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "mike",
    "salary": 1300
  }
]
```

my project is three parts.
first the user can enter an Int in a `EditText` widget to display a toast of the name of corresponding  to the id .
third is a min max search ,the user enters two `Integers` to search for all salaries between them .
but the second part is where I'm having problems, i have a `spinner` of employee names the  user should select a name then clicks the `btnSearchName` Button  to display the info of the  corresponding  user (id name and salary) in a  `TextView` in the `Search_by_name.xml`,but when i click the search `button` I'm taken to the XML file but the `employeeInfo`TextView is Empty,and There are no Error messages or crashes just an empty activity and i cant figure it out.

this the **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.hfad.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editId = findViewById(R.id.editId);
        final EditText editMin = findViewById(R.id.editMin);
        final EditText editMax = findViewById(R.id.editMax);
        final Spinner spName = findViewById(R.id.spinnerName);

        final String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/dxnri";

        final ArrayList<String> employeeName = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonArrayRequest jsonSpinner = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                null,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject st = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = st.getString("name");
                        employeeName.add(name);
                    }
                    spName.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, employeeName));
                } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            } }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("error", error.toString());
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getMInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonSpinner);

        Button btnSearchId = findViewById(R.id.btnSearchId);
        btnSearchId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                JsonArrayRequest jsonId = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        null,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            boolean found = false;
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                String name;
                                JSONObject st = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                int id = st.getInt("id");
                                if(id == Integer.parseInt(editId.getText().toString())) {
                                    name = st.getString("name");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "The employee's name is " + name,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    found = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(!found)
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Id",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    } }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("error", error.toString());
                    }
                });
                MySingleton.getMInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonId);
            }
        });

        Button btnSearchName = findViewById(R.id.btnSearchName);
        btnSearchName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchByName.class);
                intent.putExtra("EmployeeName", spName.getSelectedItem().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button btnSearchSalary = findViewById(R.id.btnSearchSalary);
        btnSearchSalary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchBysalary.class);
                intent.putExtra("salaryMin", editMin.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("salaryMax", editMax.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout tools:context=".MainActivity" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSearchId"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerName"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="id"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editId"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editMax"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="salary min"
        android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/editMin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSearchSalary"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="salary max"
        android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/editMax"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSearchName"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchId"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="SEARCH BY ID"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSearchSalary"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="SEARCH BY NAME"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchSalary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="SEARCH BY SALARY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSearchName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSearchSalary"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.493"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.688"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the **SearchByName.java**

```
package com.hfad.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SearchByName extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_by_name);

        final TextView employeeInfo = findViewById(R.id.employeeInfo);
        final String employeeName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");


        final Spinner spName = findViewById(R.id.spinnerName);


        String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/dxnri";


        JsonArrayRequest jsonName = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                null,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject st = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = st.getInt("id");
                        String name = st.getString("name");
                        int salary = st.getInt("salary");

                        if(name.equals(employeeName)) {
                            employeeInfo.setText("Id: " + id + "\n\nName: " + name + "\n\nSalary: " + salary);

                            break;
                            //   "Id: " + id + "\n\nName: " + name + "\n\nSalary: " + salary

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            } }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("error", error.toString());
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getMInstance(SearchByName.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonName);
    }
}
```

and `searchbyname.XML` where the Name,id,Salary of the Selected Name from the `spinnerName` should be displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout tools:context=".SearchByName" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/employeeInfo"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem that you trying to start the same activity that is already started.That wouldn't work. `onCreated` is not called again if activity is running.

You should do one of this:

- ovveride in your `MainActivity` method `onNewIntent` and do all the JSON logic here
- forget about intents and use `AsyncTask` (deprecated) or other async pattern to do the job

Answer (score 0):

In the `MainActivity.java` you put an extra for the Intent:

```
intent.putExtra("EmployeeName", spName.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

But in the `SerachByName.java` you retrieve it like that:

```
final String employeeName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

The `key` is different, please change `"name"` to `"EmployeeName"` in `SearchByName.java`

In addition - cool thing for you would be learning Retrofit and rxJava for API requests like that.

Comment: it worked ,not the first time i scratched my head over simple mistake ,but now that it worked the world is a nice place again ,thanks.